# Concatenate many videos and one sound with ffmpeg

Tags: macos, terminal, ffmpeg

I'm trying to concatenate many `mp4` videos (h264) with an audio `mp3`.

I searched hover the internet and [the docs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat)

Example, I have:

- 3 mp4 videos (with audio) of 15 seconds each
- 1 mp3 audio of 60 seconds

I dont want to keep the audio of the videos but I want the `mp3` file to became the only audio mapped over the whole videos.

```
[          audio          ]
[video 1][video 2][video 3]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic syntax is

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4 -i 3.mp4 -i audio.mp3 -filter_complex "[0][1][2]concat=3[v]" -map "[v]" -map 3:a -shortest out.mp4
```

Comment: I got an error with that command: `ffmpeg -i video_a.mp4 -i video_b.mp4 -i sound.mp3 -filter_complex "[0][1][2] concat=3[v]" -map "[v]" -map 3:a -shortest concat.mp4`. The error is `Stream specifier '' in filtergraph description [0][1][2] concat=3[v] matches no streams.`

Comment: My command is for three videos. Yours is for two. Remove `[2]` and change to `concat=2`

Comment: Additionally, is there a possibility to make the sound restart at each video start ?

Comment: The easiest way to do that is a two command process: Run for each file `ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i audio.mp3 -map 0:v -map 1:a -c copy -shortest 1a.mp4` and then `ffmpeg -i 1a.mp4 -i 2a.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v][0:a][1:v][1:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" concat.mp4`

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mulvya, do you know a great place to learn ffmpeg (or a book to buy) ?